# How to find by an array property using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
Products:[
  {
    name: "PSP"
    tags: ["psp","sony","videogames"]
    price: 50
  },
  {
    name: "XBOX ONE"
    tags: ["xbox","one","videogames"]
    price: 50
  },
  {
    name: "Nintendo Wii"
    tags: ["wii","nintendo","videogames"]
    price: 50
  }
]
```

I'm trying to filter this list by tags and I expect to get the array

```
mongoose.model('products').find({'Products.tags':'PSP'});
```

What I want is this

```
 {
    name: "PSP"
    tags: ["psp","sony","videogames"]
    price: 50
  }
```

It doesn't work!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get? And what are you getting?

Comment: Specifically what doesn't work about what you're trying?

Comment: the return is null, I'm trying to get the array like the example if I find "PSP" I want all the data of the array contains it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDB does case-sensitive compare on strings. You're trying to find a string that's upper-case `PSP` but, your document contains lower-case strings `psp`.

You can try it like this:

```
mongoose.model('products').findOne({'Products.tags':'psp'}).exec(
    function(err, docs) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log(docs.tags);
});
```